# How to assert (if there are any) duplicates in unit tests?

Tags: c#, linq, list, unit-testing, stub

I know with

```
Assert.IsFalse(postsPageOne.Intersect(postsPageTwo).Any());
```

you can compare to objects to find any duplicates.

But I want to check if my list contains duplicates, after I used it in my method. Here is the test code:

```
///ARRANGE
///
var toShuffle = new List<int>(){
    1001,
    1002,
    1003,
    1004,
    1005,
    1006,
    1007,
    1008,
    1009,
    1010
};

///ACT
///
toShuffle = Shared_Components.SharedComponents.Shuffle(toShuffle, 10);

///ASSERT
///
Assert.IsTrue(toShuffle.Count == 10, "Number of Elements not correct!");
Assert.IsTrue(toShuffle.All(a => a >= 1001 && a <= 1010), "Elements out of range!");
```

Comment: You should really be using Assert.AreEqual(10, toShuffle.Count, "Number of Elements not correct!"), instead of Assert.IsTrue(). It will make your failed test reports much more useful.

Comment: @Grant Winney: The Shuffle() method changes the [index] position of every numbers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using [FluentAssertions](http://www.fluentassertions.com) (which I *highly* recommend), you can do:

```
toShuffle.Should().OnlyHaveUniqueItems();
```

But, I'd actually rewrite your test like this:

```
//Arrange
var original = new List<int>{1001,1002,1003,1004,1005,1006,1007,1008,1009,1010};

//Act 
var shuffled = Shared_Components.SharedComponents.Shuffle(original , 10);

//Assert
shuffled.Should().BeEquivalentTo(original)
    .And.NotBeAscendingInOrder();
```

The purpose of the test is now much easier to understand.

Answer (score 6):

Look at the amount of distinct values (`toShuffle.Distinct().Count())` and verify is that is the same as the initial amount.

I would also advise you to use the proper assertion methods instead of using `Assert.IsTrue()` everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe my explanations were not good enough and/or the example was inappropriate.

Here is how I solved it:

```
///ARRANGE
///
var toShuffle = new List<int>(){1001, 1002,1003, 1004, 1005, 1006, 1007, 1008, 1009, 1010};
var expected = new List<int>() { 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006, 1007, 1008, 1009, 1010 };

///ACT
///
toShuffle = Shared_Components.SharedComponents.Shuffle(toShuffle, 10);

///ASSERT
///
Assert.AreEqual(10, toShuffle.Count, "Number of Elements wrong!");
Assert.IsTrue(toShuffle.All(a => a >= 1001 && a <= 1010), "Elements out of range!");

//to check if there are any duplicates
toShuffle.Sort();
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, toShuffle, "Duplicates found!");
```

If the first two asserts are true and the last fails, then there must be at least one duplicate between 1001 - 1010.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it in NUnit (using the newer assertion notation):

`Assert.That(toShuffle, Is.Unique);`